# System.InvalidOperationException: 'Cannot assign a native control without an Element;

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp, custom-renderer

I am working on a project "CoManga" and I wanted to add advertisements in it. Implementing ads on UWP seemed straight forward, like Android and iOS. However, I'm stuck now.

Anyways, I followed [this tutorial by James Montemagno](https://montemagno.com/xamarin-forms-uwp-ads/) and added everything. I even see the test advertisements, which is great. However, when I try to move away from that page (when I press "BACK Button") and go to previous page, I get an error.

This is the error :

`Setting up AdControlView in UWP throws System.InvalidOperationException: 'Cannot assign a native control without an Element; Renderer unbound and/or disposed. Please consult Xamarin.Forms renderers for reference implementation of OnElementChanged.'.`

It is thrown at [line number 50](https://github.com/Xonshiz/CoManga/blob/master/src/comic_dl/comic_dl.UWP/customRenderer/AdViewRenderer.cs), where I set the `SetNativeControl(adView);`. I've commented it out right now, but as soon as I un-comment it, I see this error.

Can someone help me out here with this.

Comment: Does the following answer work?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't been able to put this one around. So couldn't check. Will try to check it this evening and will mark it as solved if it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Setting up AdControlView in UWP throws System.InvalidOperationException: 'Cannot assign a native control without an Element; Renderer unbound and/or disposed. Please consult Xamarin.Forms renderers for reference implementation of OnElementChanged.

The reason is that xamarin Element has released but `SetNativeControl` invoked again cause the native control can't find the matched xamarin Element when page going back. So you could set a flag (`isRegist`) to record the registed ad.

```
public class AdViewRenderer : ViewRenderer<AdControlView, AdControl>
{
    string bannerId = "test";
    AdControl adView;
    string applicationID = "3f83fe91-d6be-434d-a0ae-7351c5a997f1";
    bool isRegist = false;

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<AdControlView> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (Control == null && isRegist != true)
        {
            CreateNativeAdControl();
            SetNativeControl(adView);
            isRegist = true;
        }
    }
    private void CreateNativeAdControl()
    {
        if (adView != null)
            return;

        var width = 300;
        var height = 50;
        if (AnalyticsInfo.VersionInfo.DeviceFamily == "Windows.Desktop")
        {
            width = 728;
            height = 90;
        }
        // Setup your BannerView, review AdSizeCons class for more Ad sizes. 
        adView = new AdControl
        {
            ApplicationId = applicationID,
            AdUnitId = bannerId,
            HorizontalAlignment = Windows.UI.Xaml.HorizontalAlignment.Center,
            VerticalAlignment = Windows.UI.Xaml.VerticalAlignment.Bottom,
            Height = height,
            Width = width
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: I am still getting the error after coming back from a page that diplays an ad. If I check `isRegist != true` I do not get any ad on Previous Page. If I remove it, I get the same error. On the First Page I only get ad when the app is launched. after that when coming back from Next Page, either I get that error or I don't get any ad.